# Right-to-left numbers in HTML

Tags: html, right-to-left

I need to format two numbers in HTML. Sometimes they are embedded in left-to-right text, sometimes in right-to-left text.

In left-to-right mode I want the numbers to appear as 12<sup>34</sup>, in right-to-left mode I want <sup>34</sup>12.

I try this HTML code:

```
<p style="direction: rtl;">12&#x200b;<sup>34</sup></p>
<p style="direction: ltr;">12&#x200b;<sup>34</sup></p>
```

(`&#x200b;` is a zero-width space.)

In Internet Explorer 9, this gives me exactly what I want; but in Firefox 19 and Chrome 24 I get 12<sup>34</sup> in both cases (although the browsers correctly align the text to the right).

Which browsers work as they should? How can I achieve the Internet Explorer behaviour in all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that IE is wrong here, because U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE has Bidi Class BN (Boundary Neutral), which means, by the [Unicode bidi algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/), that it shall be ignored in the algorithm. And a string of common digits is rendered left to right.

Using U+200A HAIR SPACE instead fixes this (its Bidi Class is WS, Whitespace), though it has the effect of creating a little extra space, and some really old browsers like IE 6 may display it as a box. Using it, you would write

```
<p style="direction: rtl;">12&#x200a;<sup>34</sup></p>    
<p style="direction: ltr;">12&#x200a;<sup>34</sup></p>
```

Comment: Thank you, Jukka, that works. I'm just puzzled that Unicode doesn't have a zero-width space that works the same way that the hair space does.

Answer (score 0):

**A possible solution would be wrapping each digit with a `<span>` tag**. That's pretty safe.

You can probably program a javascript/jQuery function to iterate through `<p>` tags of a specific class, and wrap each digit inside them with a `<span>` tag, while giving the right styling for the `<sup`> digits.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to actually display both versions and use CSS styling to display the correct version:

```
<sup class="rightLeft">34</sup>12<sup class="leftRight">34</sup>
```

...then set-up your CSS in the different stylesheets like so:

Style sheet 1 - Left to right format:

```
.rightLeft {display: none;}
```

Style sheet 2 - Right to left format:

```
.leftRight {display: none;}
```